# Create my @display

Tags: orchardcms

I have N modules that use same dropdown list (data I take from the server),
I want do something generic when I write `@display.X()`
that display the dropdown that I created,

what's the best practice to do that?

that's ok write the code into Themes -> TheAdmin -> Views -> X.cshtml?

Comment: If it is just the appearance, you can put it in your theme. If it is functionality you're going to add, you can create a separate module with that dropdown view, and lay a dependency on that module from your other modules.

Comment: ok, I understood thanks

Comment: `Display.X` will basically render a shape named **X**. If you don't know what a shape is or how it works, then i recommend reading some docs like http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Accessing-and-rendering-shapes